# Runtime Error: Unknown MATLAB location when using a wrapper in python

Tags: python, matlab, ipython, spyder

I am trying to use a Matlab wrapper for my code in the ipython spyder IDE. 
I get the following error when I run the code:

```
raise RuntimeError("Unknown MATLAB location: try to initialize MatlabSession with matlab_root set properly.")

RuntimeError: Unknown MATLAB location: try to initialize MatlabSession with matlab_root set properly.
```

I'm hoping this is a simple fix to import a module or change a setting in spyder. Or if anyone knows how to set the matlab_root? Any help would be much appreciated, Thank You!

Comment: pleaso do not screenshot code/errors, put them as text

Comment: What is the value of `matlab_root` ? where is MATLAB installed?

Comment: Ive change to code as text, sorry :) I have no idea what the value of matlab_root is and wouldn't know how to check. Matlab is installed in my applications folder as I'm running on a mac.

Comment: Thank You! I had to go into the python file for matlab_wrapper and manually set matlab_root. I think this may be due to my version of Matlab but it is all working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically matlab_root is a variable inside `MatlabSession`, that points to the folder where MATLAB is installed. What is happening here is that probably matlab_root has a default value that is not where your MATLAB is installed. you need to change/set this variable to the folder where MATLAB is installed.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: @user32882 From OP: *"I had to go into the python file for matlab_wrapper and manually set matlab_root."*

Comment: which python file? There are 3 different ones: __init__.py, matlab_session.py and typeconv.py

Comment: @user32882 I don't remember. Try CNTR+F "matlab_root"

Answer (score 0):

**Set the environment** directly in the code, e.g. (Mac OS)

```
import matlab_wrapper
matlab = matlab_wrapper.MatlabSession(matlab_root='/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app')
```

or try to **set the environment variable** via command line, e.g. (again Mac)

```
echo matlab_root='/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app'
```

Also, see the matlab_wrapper FAQ: https://github.com/mrkrd/matlab_wrapper/blob/master/FAQ.rst

An additional option is to use the **native wrapper** (matlab-engine) from Mathworks, see here:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html